# How can I remove the small components in an image after using morphological thinning?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I tried to use morphological thinning and the output has some noise. I'm using python. The first image is the original image.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaP2q.png)

This is the code I tried for thinning (partially taken from [OpenCV Python Tutorials](https://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/skeletonization-using-opencv-python.html)):

```
from skimage import morphology
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('m.png',0);

size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)

ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
done = False

while (not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img, element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img, temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel, temp)
    img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros == size:
        done = True

'cleaned = morphology.remove_small_objects(skel, min_size=64, connectivity=2) I tried to use this function to remove the noise but it gave the same output'
```

This is the output image.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwl6l.png)

This is what I got when I changed the structuring element to:

```
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
```

[MORPH_RECT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64luI.png)

The desired output is to get a thinned image without any noise. Can anyone please help me remove these small dots(noise)?

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPcan.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a **gaus filter** should do it.

```
cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1), [Theory + Examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)

Besides Filtering you could use a **opening** operation:

```
opening = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) see point 3

---

My results: to prove that it works [image: resulting picture]

It also takes away something from the input image but thats because of the tiny resolution. You can further tweak the parameters.

```
kernel = np.ones((2,1),np.uint8)
skel = cv2.morphologyEx(skel, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('end_product.png',skel)
```

Comment: It only blurred the image but didn't remove the noise

Comment: I got the same output again

Comment: @H. Nagaty when do you blur the image? Before or after the thresholding?

Comment: @pierrom I blur the image after the thresholding(after the while loop before showing the output)

Comment: @ohlr Should I add it before thresholding or after?

Comment: I tried to use the code you posted, it gave me the same output as yours. But I want the ridges to be connected.

Comment: Well, you might have to work on other parts of your code for this to work - or increase the image resolution.  The problem right now is that your object only has a width of 1px. Its hard to distinguish between object and noise.

A hint, try different shapes for your structuring element and different sizes. 

Besides you might try to calculate the area each object in your image. And than discard those with too small area https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: Actually I don't know from where I can accept answers, I'm a new user. Can you please tell me from where I can accept it? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Found it. Thank you.